# Redirecting to named route using middleware yields page not found

Tags: laravel

I have the following routes in my web.php file:

```
Route::get('/', 'PostsController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/login', 'SessionsController@show');
```

SessionController class has a public constructor that uses Laravel's middleware to check if a user is a guest:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class SessionsController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct() {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except(['destroy']);

    public function create() {

        // Validade form data
        $this->validate(request(), [
            'email' => 'required',
            'password' => 'required'
        ]);

        // Attempt to authenticate the user
        if(! auth()->attempt(request(['email', 'password']))) {
            return back()->withErrors([
                'message' => 'Please check you credentials and try again'
            ]);
        }
        return redirect()->home();
    }
    public function show() {
        return view('login.show');
    }

    public function destroy() {
        auth()->logout();
        return redirect()->home();
        //return redirect()->route('home');
    }
}
```

What happens is that when i'm logged in and i try to access `/login` i'm being redirected to `home` but i get a "sorry, page not found" in the browser. I understood that the middleware checks if i'm a guest when i try to login, if i'm not it should redirect me to the refereed page.

I checked `php artisan route:list` and i can see that `/` is assigned the name `home`. I'm out of ideas now and i will appreciate any help.

Comment: Your PostsController has an index method correct?

Comment: @mattQuest Yes, i have.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
return redirect()->route('home');
```

Comment: Although you only mention this fragment i suppose it will not have any effect because the issue is related to the constructor and the middleware will handle what page is being redirected. Thank you for the attention.